# Object reference... How do I know where in the site an error is happening and why?

Tags: 2sxc

This is what I have from the Site Log, but not information where is happening not event in what Portal, any ideas?

```
at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) 
at ToSic.Eav.Apps.ZoneManager.get_Languages() 
at ToSic.SexyContent.Environment.Dnn7.ZoneMapper.CulturesWithState(Int32 tennantId, Int32 zoneId) 
in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\Environment\Dnn7\ZoneMapper.cs:line 51 
at ToSic.SexyContent.Environment.Dnn7.ClientInfosLanguages..ctor(PortalSettings ps, Int32 zoneId) 
in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\Environment\Dnn7\RenderingHelpers.cs:line 211 
at ToSic.SexyContent.Environment.Dnn7.ClientInfosAll..ctor(String systemRootUrl, PortalSettings ps, ModuleInfo mic, SxcInstance sxc, UserInfo uinfo, Int32 zoneId, Boolean isCreated) 
in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\Environment\Dnn7\RenderingHelpers.cs:line 130 
at ToSic.SexyContent.Environment.Dnn7.RenderingHelpers.GetClientInfosAll() 
in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\Environment\Dnn7\RenderingHelpers.cs:line 83 
at ToSic.SexyContent.SxcInstance.Render() in C:\Projects\2SexyContent\Web\DesktopModules\ToSIC_SexyContent\SexyContent\SxcInstance.cs:line 211
```

Thanks in advance for any pointers.
Regards,

Comment: My bad, Evoq 9.1.0 & 2sxc 9.2.0

Answer (score 0):

DNN always adds Portal info - but if it doesn't, I'm guessing it is caused by the search index running in the background or something. But this is just a guess.